# How to get random single result from multiple rows text from web scraping using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way for me to straight away get random single result from the row and output it without having to push to the `healthArray`?

My main objective is to increase the performance because the row can be up to 200+ text and I don't want it to keep pushing to the array.

```js
let randomFact;
let healthArray = []

$(".round-number")
  .find("h3")
  .each(function(i, el) {
    let row = $(el).text().replace(/(\s+)/g, " ");
    row = $(el)
      .text()
      .replace(/[0-9]+\. /g, "")
      .trim();
    healthArray.push(row);
  });

randomFact = healthArray[
  Math.floor(Math.random() * healthArray.length)
].toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the random number then use `eq()` to pull the text of the random element straight from the DOM. This would negate the need to build the array.

```
let $h3 = $('.round-number h3');
let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $h3.length);
let randomFact = $h3.eq(rnd).text().replace(/[0-9]+\. /g, '').trim();
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let $h3 = $('.round-number h3');

$('button').on('click', () => {
  let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $h3.length);
  let randomFact = $h3.eq(rnd).text().replace(/[0-9]+\. /g, '').trim();
  console.log(randomFact);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get random</button>

<div class="round-number"><h3>Foo</h3></div>
<div class="round-number"><h3>Bar</h3></div>
<div class="round-number"><h3>Fizz</h3></div>
<div class="round-number"><h3>Buzz</h3></div>
<div class="round-number"><h3>Lorem</h3></div>
<div class="round-number"><h3>Ipsum</h3></div>
```